Who's that Pokémon?
Trainer LEO would like to battle.

Trainer LEO sent out CATERPIE
Trainer LEO sent out RATICATE
Trainer LEO sent out NIDORINA
Trainer LEO sent out DIGLETT
Trainer LEO sent out SLOWBRO
Trainer LEO sent out ________

Trainer LEO smiles at you, "Can you figure out what my last Pokémon is?" and hands you a note - "It's not a sequence, nor a list"

Jynx, Mew, Beedrill, Nidoran♂, Miltank, Klink, Nihilego, Kabutops, Silcoon, Kakuna, Snivy, Absol, Lapras, Aron, Dartrix, Sawk, Minun, Gyarados, Onix, Durant, Shinx, Metang, Paras, Zorua, Marill, Klang, Cherrim, Pidgeot, Tentacool, Hoopa, Oddish, Houndoom, Bellsprout, Unown, Zapdos, Golem, Muk, Jirachi, Ferroseed, Riolu, Komala, Gorebyss, Pikachu, Machamp, Joltik, Skitty, Ariados, Ditto, Dodrio, Murkrow, Sliggoo, Golisopod


What is his last Pokémon? It is NOT in the list

Hint 1:

 Since this is not a list, let's strip it from the item separator , :JynxMewBeedrillNidoran♂MiltankKlinkNihilegoKabutopsSilcoonKakunaSnivyAbsolLaprasAronDartrixSawkMinunGyaradosOnixDurantShinxMetangParasZoruaMarillKlangCherrimPidgeotTentacoolHoopaOddishHoundoomBellsproutUnownZapdosGolemMukJirachiFerroseedRioluKomalaGorebyssPikachuMachampJoltikSkittyAriadosDittoDodrioMurkrowSliggooGolisopod

Hint 2:

 The title also functions as a hint.

Hint 3:

 The message in hint 1 has a length of 323 characters. The fact that 323 is the first Fibonacci pseudoprime is just a happy coincidence.

Hint 4:

 You will need to put your skills at a slight variation of the game "Who's that Pokémon" to the test. The answer will not be given to you.


+1 just because it’s a pokemon themed puzzle

The Pokédex numbers of the five Pokémon that Trainer LEO sent out are 10, 20, 30, 50, and 80.  That leads me to believe that this is a Fibonacci sequence, and the next one should be 130.  Except that's Gyarados, who is in the names given, and the last sentence seems to imply that none of those names are the answer...

Hm. GPR's observations, which are supported by the trainer's name, and the hint could lead to a useful indexing scheme to extract an eight-letter word, but either it doesn't work out or I'm just not seeing it.

Clearly the names are the source of some information, as is the trainer's name. The particular random-looking order of the wrong pokémons isn't in fact very random, giving a clue that there really is some hidden information there. Yet, I'm still empty-handed.

Also, I'm starting to suspect that the answer is some glitch pokémon.

Oy! Everything seems to point towards Farfetch'd now ... ;)

I have two thoughts: the first thought is that the Pokémon list above is some sort of raw text file that can potentially convert into a jpeg/png/etc file. Idk if that makes any sense to anyone, but I’m looking at the steganography tag and thinking that in some twisted way that text file translate into some sort of photo.

rot13{Gur frpbaq gubhtug zvtug or n pbvapvqrapr ohg V pbhagrq gur vaqvivqhny yrggref nppbeqvat gb gur Cbxéqrk ahzore bs gur nobir Cbxézbaf, erfgnegvat nsgre uvggvat gung ahzore. Fb wlakzrjorRqevyyavqbevab♂zvygnaX, rgp. juvpu tnir zr RXNABV, juvpu vf fhfcvpvbhfyl fvzvyne gb RXNAF}

Hm. Steganography can work on texts, too. But the game that was mentioned works with [fvyubhrggrf], I think, so you might be right. Hint 3 is perhaps a red herring and just wants to point us to the length of the string: 17×19.

Ooh you might be onto something there!

@MOehm Indeed, this has been my working hypothesis too. I think finding the right 'keyword' is the trick here...

The game revolving around [fvyubhrggrf] was why I was inclined to think that the text file itself could spit out an image. But what if [Nsgre betnavmvat vg vagb n 17k19 tevq naq gura znlor oybggvat bhg yrggref nppbeqvat gb gur Svobanppv frdhrapr vg cebqhprf fbzr fbeg bs funcr? Ohg gura jul unir Cbxézba anzrf va gur svefg cynpr?] I unfortunately have lab in 10 minutes and my laptop died so I don’t have a chance to try this theory until a few hours later

@PrinceNorthLæraðr I don't think it's about the sequence. I think rot13(gur anzrf jvyy unir orra fcrpvnyyl pubfra fb gung oybggvat bhg gur tevq'f yrggref sebz n cnegvphyne pbqrjbeq jvyy yrnir n erpbtavfnoyr fvyubhrggr. Fb sne V unir gevrq YRBANEQB, SVOBANPPV naq TLNENQBF (gur arkg Cbxézba va gur frdhrapr) ohg abguvat vf yrncvat bhg ng zr...)

@Stiv have you tried any of those in 19 x17?

@PrinceNorthLæraðr That, and the other way round

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Okay, guys, I have it. The pokémon looks like this. It shouldn't be hard to identify, but I haven't done so yet. If any of you Pokéwhizzes out there wants to lend me an eye here, I'd be grateful. That's a very cool puzzle, by the way.

@MOehm Gung vzntr vf gbb ybj erfbyhgvba gb or pyrne rabhtu, ohg ybbxf yvxr n Gbgbqvyr sbe zr.

The last Pokémon is:

 Totodile:



Observations

 The Pokédexes of the first five Pokémon that trainer Leo sent out are 10, 20, 30, 50, and 80. This is a Fibonacci series, where the each element is the sum of the previous two. The name of the trainer, Leo, hints at Leonardo da Pisa, anoter name of Fibonacci.

 The title is the name of the online game Who's that Pokémon, where players must recognize Pokémon by their silhouettes. Four options are given, like in Who Wants to be a Millionaire.

 The given names have 323 letters (including one symbol) in total when run together without spaces and commas. These letters can be arranged in a rectangle of either 17×19 or 19×17.

The answer:

 After a bit of experimentation, I got a promising bitmap. (I highlighted each letter individually in both orientations and looked for letters that never appear near the corners, which led me to U, M, A and H.)

 The letters are arranged in 19 lines with 17 letters each in the same order as they appear in Hint 1. Now highlight the letters whose position in the alphabet form the beginning of the canonical Fibonacci series 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, ...: A, B, C, E, H and U:


· · · · M E · B E E · · · · · · ·
· · · A · · M · · · A · · · · · ·
· · · H · · E · · · A B U · · · ·
· · · C · · · · A · U · A · · · ·
· A B · · · · A · · A · A · · · ·
A · · · · · · A · · M · · U · · ·
A · A · · · · · · · · U · A · · ·
H · · · M E · A · · · A · A · · ·
· U A M A · · · · · · A · · C H E
· · · M · · · · E · · · E · · A C
· · · H · · · A · · · · · H H · U
· · · · M B E · · · · · · U · U ·
· · · · A · · · · · · · E M M U ·
· · · A C H · · E · · · · E E · ·
· · · U · · M A · A · · · E B · ·
· · · · A C H U M A C H A M · · ·
· · · · · · · · · · A · · A · · ·
· · · · · · · · · · · M U · · · ·
· · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · ·


The answer in colour

 

Credit

 Many of the obervations are taken from the comments below the question. So thanks to everyone who shared their findings, especially to GentlePurpleRain who spotted the Fibonacci pattern and to MrClarinico for identifying the Pokémon.


I think it looks like a ROT13(Gbgbqvyr)

Aha well done! And I agree with MrClarinico's ID above...

Oh, thank you, @MrClarinico. In the catalogues I browsed, the mouth was wide open, so I missed that completely.

Yes, good job! Side Node: rot13(Perqvgf gb WrsserlZNA1234 sbe gur cvkry neg (gur bayl ernfba vg qbrfa'g unir gur rknpg fnzr oynpx pryyf vf orpnhfr V znqr genafpevcgvba reebef :)). V ernyvmr gur lryybj cneg vf gbb sne qbja va gur yvaxrq neg, ohg gung'f jung vg vf fhccbfrq gb or svyyrq yvxr.)

Good job creating the puzzle, I'd say. So the mouth is actually open and where I put the yellow stripe. Anyway, I'll leavit it as it is, since you have linked to the original art.

Ahh…I thought I had to highlight the capitals no wonder I couldn’t get the Pokémon

Ah, good solve! That was a very sharp solve... and a really cool puzzle from @LukasRotter!
